# send data from activity to fragment dynamicly

Tags: android, android-fragments

As the title said,how can I send data from activity to fragment **dynamicly**?

For example,every time when I change the value in activity when trigger the event,I must transfer this value to fragment,then the fragment will make some changes according this value.

Notice that it is dynamic,instead of :

```
public static VideoFragment instance(String videourl, String bannerurl) {
        VideoFragment fragment = new VideoFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("videourl", videourl);
        bundle.putString("bannerurl", bannerurl);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

This occurs when initialize the fragment,and **it does not meet the requirement**.

Please tell me how to handle with it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the trigger that value in your activity has changed?

Comment: yeah,on onkeyDown event

Comment: And value in your activity changes when your fragment is already visible? and that's when you want to change values in your showing fragment? (I had little difficulty in understanding your question)

Comment: every time when I change the value in activity when trigger the event,I must transfer this value to fragment,then the fragment will make some changes according this value.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a method to your VideoFragment class, you can directly call fragment.methodName(Param param); after you have created the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your attribute in your class and create a setter (in public ) in it to be able to modify your attribute.

> 

```
public class VideoFragment
{

    private String _videoUrl; // video url

    public void setVideoUrl(String url) // your setter
    {
        _videoUrl = url;
    }


    public static VideoFragment instance(String videourl, String bannerurl) {
        VideoFragment fragment = new VideoFragment();
        fragment.setVideoUrl(videourl); //set the value of your video url into your fragment
        // do the same for your banner
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

PS : Never add any parameters to the constructor of your fragment, you might avoid some random crashs. Android does not recommend it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add one method like `setNewData(newData)` in your `VideoFragment`

   ```
   public void setNewData(newData)
   {

      //update fragment based on 'new Data'
   }
   ```
2. In your `Activity`, find out `VideoFragmeny` and send new data by:

   ```
   VideoFragment vFrag = (VideoFragment)getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
   vFrag.setNewData(newData);
   ```

   if you use suppot library in your Activity, then use
   `getSupportFragmentManager` accordingly. And also if you use `Tag` when
   create `VideoFragment` then use `findFragmentByTag` instead of
   `findFragmentById` in above.

Answer (score 0):

it very easy send data from activity to any fragment.

Only you do is add a public method in your framents class:

```
public void Response(String data){
    Log.i("data", data);
 }
```

then, creates an instance from activity class:

```
FragmentClass obj=(FragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById
                    (R.id.main_fragment);
obj.Response("This is a string");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make your data is static. Then call YourActivity.YourData, is it dynamic?

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand what you mean **dynamically**. But it you want to access some variables which is from the Activity, you may create a method or simply access the variable by using the following

```
((Your Activity Name) getActivity()).your method
```

or

```
((Your Activity Name) getActivity()).your variable
```