# I want to transfer data from activity to fragment and then display data in the fragment. My code doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Activity class is MainActivity.java, Fragment class is frganswer.java. I am taking two numbers in the activity using edittext and then I need to display its sum in the fragment. There are no errors, but when I try to run it on the AVD, it goes 'not responding'. Please point out my mistakes.

MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    String aa,bb;
    double a,b,c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.no1);
        aa=editText1.getText().toString();
        EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.no2);
        bb=editText2.getText().toString();
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void add(View view)
    {   
    a=Integer.parseInt(aa);
    b=Integer.parseInt(bb);
    c=a+b;
    send(c);
    }
    public void send(double c)
    {
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("", c);
        frganswer ob=new frganswer();
        ob.setArguments(bundle);
    }


 }
```

frganswer.java

```
public class frganswer extends Fragment {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
           ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_answer, 
                                     container, false);

            double c=getArguments().getDouble("");
            String ans=String.valueOf(c);
            TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            t.setText(ans);


            return view;
         }
  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/no1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/no1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/no2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/no1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/no2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frg_1"
        android:name="com.example.calculator.frganswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_fragment_answer" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/no2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/no2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:onClick="add" 

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_fragment_answer.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When are you calling add()?

Comment: when the button in activity_main.xml is pressed.

Comment: get idea from my answer to [send data from activity to fragment dynamicly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934697/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-dynamicly/28937060#28937060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your fragment is declared in XML, when you create new instance in `send()` it goes nowhere. Instead in your `send()` method do something like:

```
public void send(double c)
{
    frganswer ob= (frganswer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_1);;
    ob.displaySum(c);
}
```

And in your `frganswer` add method

```
public void displaySum(double c) {
   String ans=String.valueOf(c);
   ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(ans);
}
```

Also note that according to Java conventions class names should start from capital letteer `Frganswer`

**Addition:** @Marche101 is right too. You should extract the values of `aa and bb` only *after* button was clicked and check that values entered in `EditText`s are not empty, are legal, etc. No need to do anything with `args` in fragment's `onCreate()` as it is not relevant in your case.

Comment: I made changes as told by you and Marche101, but now I am getting 'view cannot be resolved' in the following line: ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(ans);

PS: I had to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My 'view' was not globally declared. Now the app is working fine. Thank you. People like you make stackoverflow awesome.

Comment: @OjasvaJain Thumbs up! Please mark my answer as correct one and possibly vote for it and Marche101

Answer (score 1):

Move this line

```
aa=editText1.getText().toString();
```

and this line

```
bb=editText2.getText().toString();
```

in to your add() method. I assume your app is crashing as you are trying to parse an Integer when it is null or empty. You should have a error log showing you exactly the line that it crashed at to help you with this kind of problem in the future.